# wifi cannot find any devices

Tags: release-hera, wifi, networking, amd

i'm running elementary 5.1 on a huawei matebook 13 with Amd drivers. my WiFi cannot find any devices it's only working with wired connection  [image]

[image: those are the drivers]

Comment: I also posted your question at
https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-network/discussions/290

Answer (score 0):

What brand name of Wifi card are you using? try to upgrade the kernel with [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/08/mainline-install-latest-kernel-ubuntu-linux-mint/)